# Will heap allocated objects have their members allocated on the stack?

Tags: c++

Let's consider this example.

```
class StaticlyManagedObject
{
   //some class members....
}
class DynamiclyManagedObject
{
   StaticlyManagedObject _staticlyManagedObject; //is this still allocated at the stack?

}

class Foo
{
  DynamiclyManagedObject * _dynamiclyManagedObject; //will be allocated in the heap.
  Foo()
  {
      _dynamiclyManagedObject = new DynamiclyManagedObject();
  }
}
```

I have been told that when we don't use dynamic memory management in C++, things are allocated in stack and we don't need memory management.

However, in this example. we have a dynamically allocated object which is called DynamiclyManagedObject I instantiate this object within the Foo constructor. My question is what happens to the statically managed data member of the DynamiclyManagedObject?

Is it still created on the stack or.. because of the fact that DynamiclyManagedObject created in the heap, every data member of it ends up into the heap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subobject has the same storage duration as the complete object it is a part of. If an instance of `DynamiclyManagedObject` is dynamically allocated, then the `StaticlyManagedObject` member will be destroyed when the `DynamiclyManagedObject` is destroyed.

Informally, you might say that the subobject will be on the heap if and only if the complete object is on the heap. However, storage duration is the technically correct way to talk about it; heap and stack are implementation details.

Comment: Thanks so much for a good explanation. All the answers I got below is equally great. Additional thanks for mentioning storage duration. A quick search showed so many answers. Now I can look up more into it.

Answer (score 4):

`StaticlyManagedObject` is a misnomer. It's allocated dynamically, same as the parent object.

The nested class members use the same allocation method as the parent object, unless they're specifically marked `static`, in which case they aren't allocated at the time of object creation, or they're specifically allocated dynamically in constructors.

Comment: thank you for clarifying that 'StaticlyManagedObject' is allocated dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Whether a member of your class is another class, or an elementary data type:

```
class DynamiclyManagedObject
{
   StaticlyManagedObject _staticlyManagedObject;
   int some_integer;
};
```

It doesn't matter whether the class member is another class, or an elementary data type, such as an `int`. Both "_staticlyManagedObject" and "some_integer" are completely identical to each other, except for their type (of course, that's not exactly a trivial attribute). One is an `int`, the other one is some other class. The type of a class member does not affect its scope. Either the entire class is dynamically allocated, or it's not. Or it's allocated in the automatic scope (on the stack, as you say).

The only exception to the rule is a `static` class member:

```
class DynamiclyManagedObject
{
   StaticlyManagedObject _staticlyManagedObject;
   int some_integer;

   static std::string some_string;
};
```

The rules are different for `some_string`. Note that this is a real static class member, and not a class member whose type happens to be `StaticallyManagedObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the type (be it a struct, class or primitive), when using the **new operator** in C++ or dynamic allocation in C with **malloc** (which gets the size of your struct as parameter, to know how many bytes to allocate) - all of the space required (containing members) *will be placed on the heap*.

These calls return a pointer to the heap memory zone which was allocated.

*Local function variables and parameters are always placed on the stack*.

If you declare a pointer local variable its place will still be on the stack, but you will have to use the dynamic allocation methods mentioned above  to allocate heap memory to which your stack-allocated pointer will actually point to.